# Oracle Using JSON_VALUE to get Array Property JSON returnning NULL

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I need to get the value of property x, but, aways return null

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('[{a:100}, {b:200}, {c:[{xico:1}]}]', '$.c') AS value
  FROM DUAL;
```

This works:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('[{a:100}, {b:200}, {c:[{xico:1}]}]', '$.a') AS value
  FROM DUAL;
```

and returns 100

how can I retrieve or c property array using JSON_VALUE?

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON has an array as the outer-most element so you need to dereference that first and then find the `c` key:

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE('[{a:100}, {b:200}, {c:300}]', '$[*].c') AS value FROM DUAL;
```

outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE |
> | :---- |
> | 300   |
> ```

and since you have additional nested arrays and objects then:

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE('[{a:100}, {b:200}, {c:[{xico:1}]}]', '$[*].c[0].xico') AS value FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE |
> | :---- |
> | 1     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5892cb9c3636b0d570b246d01a65da64)*

Answer (score 3):

JSON_VALUE is a function that converts a scalar value in the JSON to a SQL scalar value. This is why the expression with $.a works - the associated value (100) is a scalar (number) value.
On the other hand the path expression $.c selects a complex value, namely the array [{xico:1}]. Complex value can be returned with the JSON_QUERY function.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY('[{a:100}, {b:200}, {c:[{xico:1}]}]', '$.c') AS value FROM DUAL; 
[{"xico" : 1}]
```

The JSON_QUERY function also allows to select scalar values and return them wrapped in an array if you use the WITH WRAPPER clause.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY('[{a:100}, {b:200}, {c:[{xico:1}]}]', '$.a' with wrapper) AS value FROM DUAL; 
[100]
```

By the way: NULL is returned by default if an error is encountered when evaluating the path expression. You can change this default by supplying the ERROR ON ERROR clause:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('[{a:100}, {b:200}, {c:[{xico:1}]}]', '$.c' ERROR ON ERROR) FROM DUAL; 
ORA-40456: JSON_VALUE evaluated to non-scalar value
```

or

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY('[{a:100}, {b:200}, {c:[{xico:1}]}]', '$.a' ERROR ON ERROR) FROM DUAL; 
ORA-40480: result cannot be returned without array wrapper
```